# Matlab: how to verify my expression

Tags: matlab

I have a giant expression that has 6~7 symbolic terms, and they are derived by hands on a piece of paper. I want to see if my expression is correct by repeating the entire process in matlab, typing them in off course.

Now the question is, I have 2 expression, 1 from hand-derivation, and another from the matlab derivation.

How do I know two expression match?

---

Update: Let me make my question more clear, I just want to verify my hand-written derivation against with the expression typed in matlab, to see if those two match.

Comment: Can't you just look at the final result and see whether what you have by hand matches what MATLAB gives you?  Take a look at `syms` to define the symbolic variables, then use arithmetic expressions like you would by calculating by hand.  Use `simplify` to simplify your expression at the end: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html

Comment: Not sure how the computer can help you compare two things when one of them is only written on a piece of paper.  Give us a general idea of the process you're considering.

Comment: I don't know how it would be done in Matlab, but in maxima I'd simply subtract the hand-derived variant from the symbolically computed one. Sometimes some simplifications had to be performed on the result. The objective is that the result should be zero if everything went allright.

Comment: @Peter Of course one could use a camera to get it off the paper and into a digital form :) But seriously, the goal is: derive something symbolically, derive it by hand, then compare. My way of comparing is simply subtracting two things that are supposed to be the same, and expecting the result to be zero. Typing in the hand-derived formula(s) goes without saying, I hope.

Comment: You can always evaluate the both expressions in a relevant interval and see if they match